# Using regex to get text between a whitespace character and a �

Tags: java, regex

How would I use regex in Java the size/weight properties of each line in this format? The text file our teacher gave us uses a different character code which is why those weird question mark characters are present.

```
Popcorn                   Butter                             6�pkg          3.99
Laundry Detergent         2X Ultra Free Clear                50�oz          11.99
```

Getting the text between a whitespace character and the � would suffice.

Comment: `\s(.+)\u1234` (where `\u1234` code of symbol) and get first group

Comment: Probably it is a sequence of digits that can be matched with `"\\d+"`. But you'll have to locate and extract the appropriate substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regex `\s+(\d+)�`, if you are not sure if the result is a number or not you can use `.*\s+(.*?)�` instead to match any character between space and the sign � :

```
String[] strs = {
    "Popcorn                   Butter                             6�pkg          3.99",
    "Laundry Detergent         2X Ultra Free Clear                50�oz          11.99"
};

String regex = "\\s+(\\d+)�";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        //                               ^------note to get the group one
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
6
50
```